# Show popOver when right click on TableViewCell

Tags: macos, swift, nstableview, popover

I have a NSTableView and want to show a popOver if the User right click on a row. So i have this function:

```
 override func rightMouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    super.rightMouseDown(theEvent)
    var point: NSPoint = talbeView.convertPoint(theEvent.locationInWindow, fromView: nil)
    var row = tableView.rowAtPoint(point)
    var rec = tableView.rectOfRow(row)

    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let popOverViewController = storyboard!.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("RightMousPopOver") as! NSViewController
    var cell: DocumentCellView = tableView.viewAtColumn(0, row: row, makeIfNecessary: true) as! DocumentCellView
    self.presentViewController(popOverViewController, asPopoverRelativeToRect: rec, ofView: cell, preferredEdge: 2, behavior: NSPopoverBehavior.Transient)
}
```

But the popOver appears only if I right click on the first row. I have debug the row and its right. Also if i change the row manuelle, the popOver show on the right row, but again only if I click on the first row.

I'm little bit confused. What is wrong withe my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i think i found the answer. `tableView.rectOfRow(row)` is false. `cell.frame` is the right way to get the NSRec